# How to integrate fcm in react js application?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'd like to integrate fcm in react js applicaiton to provide real time chat. Any inputs to proceed?

Comment: You could use the [FCM JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) (also mentioned in this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Can-Firebase-send-push-notifications-with-React-Js-in-a-webApp)).

Comment: @AL. I'm trying to integrate it but where should I write all those `getToken`, `onTokenRefresh` methods in my code. Should I put all the code in index.html?

Answer (score 7):

My answer is a short version of related article by Leonardo Cardoso. For details check his [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1).

Adding FCM to React app is pretty straightforward. I will demonstrate on project generated via `create-react-app`.Of course, below instructions are feasible for all sort of react projects.

First of all, add `Firebase` to project.

> `npm install firebase --save`

Then, we are going to create `js` file to hold logic of our push notifications. Let's name it `push.js` and declare inside function to initialize `firebase app`.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
export const initializeFirebase = () => {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    // taken from your project settings --> cloud messaging
    messagingSenderId: "your messagingSenderId"
  });
}
```

We'll call this function in our entry point.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { initializeFirebase } from './push'; <-- add this

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
initializeFirebase(); <-- add this
```

In order to use `firebase cloud messaging`, we need a *service worker*. By default, when you start `Firebase`, it looks for a file called `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. There is a way to create and attach your own *service worker*. For simplification, we'll use the default approach.

So, we need to add `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to the location where our files are served. As we’re using the create-react-app, I’m going to add it inside the public folder with the following content:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase-app.js'); <-- check for last version
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase-messaging.js'); <-- check for last version
firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "your messagingSenderId again"
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Initial setup is done. Now you can add functionality you want: ask for permission, send notification or any other. Implementation of asking permission and sending notification is described in [the source article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging) code. You may also want to take a look into the this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58g&feature=youtu.be) tutorial as well.